# PHP SESSIONS: how do I store the quantities alongside the products which the user has added to their cart?

Tags: php

I have been trying to find this out for weeks and I'm not seeing it. how do I store the quantities alongside the products which the user has added to their cart? I need to have this because I need the users to be able to update the quantity from the items.

already tried a few things such as creating an array and trying to store quantity in a array but it only remembers the last number that the user put in. This is because its a post request. and to fix that I need to store quantities alongs side the products in cart. and thats where I'm stuck.

I tried:

```
if(isset($_POST['quantity'])){
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $_SESSION['basket'][] = $quantity;
}
```

but this put the last item a lot in the shopping cart
like this:

[image]

then I tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && !empty($_POST['quantity'])){
    $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
//           //$qty = $_SESSION["qty"] + 1;
     if (isset($_POST['broodnaam']) && !empty($_POST['broodnaam'])){  
           if ($_POST['broodnaam'] == $row['broodnaam']){
                $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
//                    //array_push($_SESSION['qty'], $quantity);
//                 //    var_dump($_SESSION['qty']);
           }
     }
}
```

but this only updates the last updated item from the cart.
I really don't know how to fix this can someone help me

code: ( part of the code as I don't feel like I need to share the styling and sessions_start() part

```
<?php
$broodjes = $_GET['broodjes_ID'];
if (isset($_SESSION['basket'])){
  if( in_array( $broodjes ,$_SESSION['basket']) )
  { 
  }else{
     $_SESSION['basket'][] = $broodjes;
  }
}else{
  $_SESSION['basket'][]= $broodjes;
}
$sumtotal = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $key => $value){
    //echo "Key = $key; value = $value; <br>";
    $sql = "SELECT broodjes_ID, broodnaam, prijs, voorraad FROM broodjes WHERE broodjes_ID=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $value);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        //session for quantity
        $_SESSION["qty"] = array();
        echo '<div class="cart-items">';
        echo '<div class="cart-row">';
        echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
        echo $row['broodnaam'];
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
        echo '€ ' . $row['prijs'];
        echo '</div>';
        //quantity
        echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">'; 
        echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
        echo '<div class="col-xs-4">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="broodnaam" id="broodnaam" value="' . $row['broodnaam'] . '">';
        echo '<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control input-sm" value="1" min="1" max="'.$row['voorraad'].'">';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
        //ik moet de quantity ergens in opslaan , denk in db, om zo nog de voorraad te verminderen
        if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && !empty($_POST['quantity'])){
            $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
            //           //$qty = $_SESSION["qty"] + 1;
            if (isset($_POST['broodnaam']) && !empty($_POST['broodnaam'])){
                if ($_POST['broodnaam'] == $row['broodnaam']){
                    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
                    ////array_push($_SESSION['qty'], $quantity);
                    ////    var_dump($_SESSION['qty']);
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
        $rowtotaal = $row['prijs'] * $quantity;
        $sumtotal += $rowtotaal;
        echo $rowtotaal;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
} 
?> <br /> 
<div class="cart-total">
    <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
    <span class="cart-total-price"> € <?php   echo $sumtotal;?></span>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: you need to make each product unique, based on that unique product_id store respective quantity

Comment: @RaoDYC how do I do that

Comment: @user18149678 you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a unique column in your products' table.

generally, the unique column is either `id` or `alias`.

Then when you need to add an item to the cart:

```
// supposing you have the product id in the $pid variable and quantity in the $qty variable
$_SESSION['cart'][$pid] = $qty;
```

Then when you need to access it you can easily loop through the session's cart.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product => $qty) {
  // do something with the product and quantity.
}
```

how this works is, it creates an item in the cart array with the index of the product's unique column value and the item's value would be the quantity of the product added to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Update the new quantity ($_POST['quantity']) by adding the old one ($_SESSION['qty']).like this -

```
   if (isset($_POST['quantity'])){  
        if (isset($_POST['broodnaam'])){
            if ($_POST['broodnaam'] == $row['broodnaam']){
                $_SESSION['qty'] = $_POST['quantity'] + $_SESSION['qty'];
            }
        }
   }
```